# C++ Sprite class with Vector Object as Member

Tags: c++, sdl, sprite, physics-engine

Ok, I'm having this problem with my Sprite class. Basically the sprite class should have a object of class Vector as its member with Vector being a class with both angle and speed. The Vector class has a Vector(double,double) constructor so the speed and angle can be set at its initialization but when I make my sprite class. It sends an error that its calling Vector(), a blank constructor, and that it doesn't exist. I'm trying to figure out why its calling Vector(). Here is my code from both the Sprite and Vector classes.

```
#Vector.h
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H

class Vector

{
    public:
        Vector(double,double);
        double getX();
        double getY();
        double getSpeed();
        double getAngle();
        void setSpeed(double);
        void setAngle(double);

    private:
        double speed,angle;
};

#endif


#Vector.h
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "math.h"

Vector::Vector(double speed,double angle)

{
    this -> speed = speed;
    this -> angle = angle;
}

double Vector::getX()

{
    return speed*cos(angle);
}

double Vector::getY()

{
    return speed*sin(angle);
}

double Vector::getSpeed()

{
    return speed;
}

double Vector::getAngle()

{
    return angle;
}

void Vector::setAngle(double angle)

{
    this -> angle = angle;
}

void Vector::setSpeed(double speed)

{
    this -> speed = speed;
}


#Sprite.h:
#ifndef SPRITE_H
#define SPRITE_H
#include "vector.h"

class Sprite

{
    public:
        Sprite(int x,int y);
        SDL_Rect getRect();
        SDL_Surface* getImage();
        void setRect(SDL_Rect);
        void move();
        void draw(SDL_Surface*);

    private:
        Vector movement;
        double x,y,lastX,lastY,angle,speed;
        SDL_Rect rect;
        SDL_Surface* image;
};

#endif


#Sprite.cpp:
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "sprite.h"
#include "functions.h"
#include <cmath>

Sprite::Sprite(int x, int y)

{
    this -> x = x;
    this -> y = y;
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
    image = loadImage("box.png");
    rect.x = x;
    rect.y = y;
    rect.w = image->w;
    rect.h = image->h;
    speed = 1;
    angle = 0;
}

SDL_Rect Sprite::getRect()

{   
    return rect;
}

SDL_Surface* Sprite::getImage()

{
    return image;
}

void Sprite::setRect(SDL_Rect rect)
{
    this -> rect = rect;
}

void Sprite::move()

{
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
    x += speed*cos(angle);
    y += speed*sin(angle);
    rect.x = int(x);
    rect.y = int(y);
}

void Sprite::draw(SDL_Surface* dest)

{
    blit(image,dest,int(x),int(y));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Sprite` class has a `Vector` member that will be constructed when the `Sprite` is constructed. At the moment, the `Vector` will be initialized with the default constructor because you haven't specified otherwise. If you want a specific constructor of `Vector` to be used, you need to add an initialization list to the constructor of `Sprite`:

```
Sprite::Sprite(int x, int y)
  : movement(1.0, 0.0)
{
  // ...
}
```

This will initialise `movement` with arguments `1` and `0`. In fact, you might as well add other members to your initialization list too:

```
Sprite::Sprite(int x, int y)
  : movement(1.0, 0.0), x(x), y(y), lastX(x), lastY(y) // and so on...
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: So if I'm reading this right your saying that i should have:

    Vector movement; //in Sprite.h file to give my Sprite class a vector member

And then in Sprite::Sprite(int x,int y) I should have something like:

    this -> x = x;
    this -> y = y;
    movement(0,1);

Please correct me if i'm wrong on this

Comment: Sprite (int x,int y) : movement(1.0,0.0)


This is what my constructor looks like now. Is this what you meant for me to do?

Comment: @DanielMiles That's right. Look up [initialization lists](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/101-constructor-initialization-lists/).

Answer (score 1):

The `Vector` is created in `Sprite::Sprite(int x, int y)`.  The blank constructor for `Vector` is called because you do not call a constructor in the initializer list: in fact, you leave the `Vector movement` completely uninitialized!

Do this:

```
Sprite::Sprite(int x, int y):
  movement(3.14, 2.7)
{
  ...
}
```

to construct `movement` using a two argument constructor.  I would pick better values than `3.14` and `2.7`, those are just sample values.

I would also consider creating a public no-argument constructor on `Vector` for ease of use that initalizes speed and angle to zero.